# how can i cancel combinations found on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

i am using windows 10, i want to disable CTRL + ALT + A combination, i searched a lot but couldn't find it

There is a program and users can enter the admin panel with this combination. I want to disable this

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10,

> Ctrl+Alt+A

is not a default keyboard shortcut for any system-wide action or function. If you are experiencing a specific issue with Ctrl+Alt+A, it may be related to a third-party application or software you have installed.

Comment: I searched for 3 hours but couldn't find it :(

Comment: but there isn't any known shortcut with Ctrl+Alt+A